# posenet failing for simple images and too slow

Tags: tensorflow

Posenet is badly estimating poses for many simple images. This make me wonder if there is any guideline we should follow to facilitate better posenet. Also it takes about 20 to 30 seconds per image be it in CPU or webgl mode. Here are the failed images (RHS image should have posenet estimation drawn)

**Settings:**
outputStride = 16, imageScaleFactor = 1,
minPartConfidence = 0.2, minPoseConfidence=0.2 (pose obtained has around 0.36 only so increasing simply does not get me any pose drawn at all)

**Example 1:**
[image]

**Example 2:** 
[image]

**Example 3:**
[image]

Obviously it then performed worse for video related to above images.

Code to reproduce the bug / link to feature request

Simply try singlePoseDetection on above images. The images are available below for testing.

1. [yoga 1](https://i.postimg.cc/pXJ7NCF9/0284.jpg)
2. [yoga 2](https://i.postimg.cc/yY1jRHDd/0002.jpg)
3. [yoga 3](https://i.postimg.cc/8PcWDPFh/0134.jpg)

I have tried multiple tuning, and I also do not see much issue with images as well. The image is clear, pose is clear, and even in 2 of test images, the bg is almost grey.

We have a demo release coming week. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

It happens sometimes. Try the new posenetv2 based on resnet models which have better accuracy.